# Fetch value from database for 2 fields and show in URL

Tags: php, mysql

**Q.** How to Extract Value from Database and paste in URL

Like i have a db table -pqrs_toys_variants 
in which there are many fields including

1. id
2. v_prod_id

Now i want to link the content of my listing page with id and v_prod_id

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_toys&view=detail&pid='.$row->v_prod_id.'&vid='.$row->id.'">Toy 1</a>
```

I been a novice learning php and mysql - really not getting a way to fetch in values of id and v_prod_id from db - #__toys_variants

can some one help and advise in it pls

Comment: Where's your code that fetches the data from the database?  What is the actual problem you've encountered?  We can sympathize with the fact that you're new to this, but it sounds like you're just asking us to teach you PHP and MySQL instead of starting with some tutorials.  That's not really what Stack Overflow does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpfull to you.

```
$data = [];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pqrs_toys_variants;");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $data[] = [$row['id], $row['v_prod_id']]
}
```

Now you can generate link like this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $item)
{
   echo "<a href=\"index.php?option=com_toys&view=detail&pid={{$row['v_prod_id']}}&vid={{$row['id']}}\">Toy {{$key}}</a>"
}
```

But as David said, you will have more luck if try something on your own and then come here.

Answer (score 0):

In below snippet I have generated a demo how to connect with DB, fetch records from DB, generate links for all the DB records and display HTML in page.

```
<?php

//Db connection
$host = "localhost";
$dbName = "test";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

//Fetch records from DB
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,v_prod_id,toy_name FROM pqrs_toys_variants");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

$HTML = "";
//Generate link for all the DB records
foreach($result as $row){
    $HTML .= '<a href="index.php?option=com_toys&view=detail&pid='.$row->v_prod_id.'&vid='.$row->id.'">'.$row->toy_name.'</a><br/>';
}
echo $HTML;
?>
```